# Yii2. Не работает ограничение частоты запросов в rest api

Tags: yii2, rest

Делал по документации, но что-то упустил. Есть rest api на yii2, нужно ограничить кол-во запросов. В web.php

```
'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        'enableSession' => false,
],
```

А сама модель User реализует интерфейс RateLimitInterface:

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface, RateLimitInterface
{

public $rateLimit = 1;
public $allowance;
public $allowance_updated_at;

...

public function getRateLimit($request, $action)
{
   return [$this->rateLimit,60];
}

public function loadAllowance($request, $action)
{
   return [$this->allowance, $this->allowance_updated_at];
}

public function saveAllowance($request, $action, $allowance, $timestamp)
{
  $this->allowance = $allowance;
  $this->allowance_updated_at = $timestamp;
  $this->save();
}
}
```

PHP скриптом отправляю запросы при помощи curl. И ограничения не действуют, можно сколько угодно отправлять запросы(аутентификация проводится при помощи HTTP Basic Auth). Что может быть упущено?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось сделать через ограничение запросов по ip адресу. В контроллере в behaviours было добавлено

```
$behaviors['rateLimiter'] = [
        'class' => RateLimiter::className(),
        'user' => new IpLimiter(),
        'enableRateLimitHeaders' => true
];
```

А сам класс IpLimiter писал все данные в таблицу в базе данных

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use app\models\Limits;
use yii\filters\RateLimitInterface;


// keep in mind, that decrease of allowed queries happened by yii2
// that updating of allowed queries in db through 60 seconds happened by yii2
class IpLimiter extends Model implements RateLimitInterface
{

public $rateLimit = 5;


// allow less queries then rateLimit for 60 seconds
public function getRateLimit($request, $action)
{
   return [$this->rateLimit,60];
}

// return remain count of allowed queries and last check time(unix timestamp)
public function loadAllowance($request, $action)
{
   $limits = Limits::find()
        ->where(['ip' => Yii::$app->getRequest()->getUserIP()])
        ->one();

   if ($limits) {
        return [$limits->allowance, $limits->timestamp];
   } else {
        return [$this->rateLimit, time()];
   }

}

// save remain count of allowed queries and current unix timestamp
public function saveAllowance($request, $action, $allowance, $timestamp)
{
  $limits = Limits::find()
        ->where(['ip' => Yii::$app->getRequest()->getUserIP()])
        ->one();

  if ($limits) {
    $limits->allowance = $allowance;
    $limits->timestamp = $timestamp;
    $limits->save();
  } else {
    $limits = new Limits();
    $limits->ip = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getUserIP();
    $limits->allowance = $allowance;
    $limits->timestamp = $timestamp;
    $limits->save();
  }
}

}
```